# How do I specify IE 11 specific css file?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I currently have a page for which I am applying some browser specific CSS styling when user clicks print button using the following html syntax. But the following html code wont apply the css specified for IE11(ie11print.css) instead it applies the css that is specified for rest of the IE versions(ieprint.css).

```
<!--[if IE 11]> <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" title="Print" type="text/css" href="/styles/ie11print.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 10]> <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" title="Print" type="text/css" href="/styles/ieprint.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>--><link rel="stylesheet" media="print" title="Print" type="text/css" href="/styles/print.css" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

Does anybody know how to specify a CSS file only for IE11?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to ...anyway IE11 doesn't support conditional comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different css for IE browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849016/different-css-for-ie-browsers)

Comment: What is IE 11 doing so differently from other browsers that you would need to include a custom stylesheet to fix it?

Comment: i have decreased the page size using zoom:70%; for all IE versions using ieprint.css file and it is working perfectly in all IE versions but in IE 11 it is much smaller compared to other IE browsers. I dont want to use zoom at all in IE11.

Comment: As @Paulie_D mentioned, Microsoft dropped conditional comments after version 9. Your IE10 conditionals won't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below hack and followed by your css style:

```
*::-ms-backdrop,
```

Example:

```
*::-ms-backdrop,/*Your element*/ {
       /*Your styles*/
    }
```

Note:It will only affects in IE browsers.So You need to apply your normal style before this.

Answer (score 5):

Just add below in your CSS stylesheet and see in Internet Explorer 11

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) 
 {                                                                                                                     
             Add your styles here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @disha. Will try this and let you know

Answer (score 1):

check for if browser is ie11

then directly add link tag from javascript

```
         window.location.hash = !!window.MSInputMethodContext;
            if (window.location.hash) 
            {
                var $head = $("head");
                var $headlinklast = $head.find("link[rel='stylesheet']:last");
                var linkElement = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/styles/ie11print.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>";
                if ($headlinklast.length){
                   $headlinklast.after(linkElement);
                }
                else {
                   $head.append(linkElement);
                }
            }
```

let me know if any concern.
window.location.hash will return true for ie11

Comment: jQuery.browser was deprecated in version 1.3 and **removed** in 1.9 (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) - I'd also have serious doubts if it can detect Internet Explorer 11 based on the significant changes to the user agent string in that version and the non-supported nature of the method.

Comment: //Appends true for IE11, false otherwise                                                       
window.location.hash = !!window.MSInputMethodContext;     you can use this robust method to detect ie11